# Как можно вывести тест из UITextField в UILabel?

Tags: swift, xcode, uitextfield, uilabel

Никак не могу введенный текст в UITextField как-нибудь обработать (добавить в переменную, сравнить с массивом и вывести соответствующий текст в UILabel.

Вот пример, почему всегда срабатывает else и выводится "!", а не "Тест"?
Да, при запуске в UITexField ничего нет, поэтому и выводится "!" но если я введу "Тест", все равно срабатывает else.

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

```
@IBOutlet weak var input: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var output: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    if input.text == "Тест" {
        output.text = input.text
    } else {
        output.text = "!"
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

viewDidLoad срабатывает только один раз, при загрузке view (посмотрите жизненный цикл viewcontroller'а). Соответственно, ввод текста в дальнейшем никак не обрабатывается. Чтобы это происходило, вам нужно сделать viewcontroller делегатом UITextField и обрабатывать события, происходящие в этом поле (ввод текста и т.п.).